# NetSuite GetValue does not work for join column

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to get a column value for the join table through SuiteScript. It does not throw error but it dont show the result either. Any tweak or tips to get the value.

```
var vendorSearchObj = search.create({
    type: "vendor",
    filters: [
       [["entityid" , "is" , "KMSS"]]
    ],
    columns: [
       search.createColumn({
          name: "entityid",
          sort: search.Sort.ASC
       }),
       "altemail",
       search.createColumn({
          name: "salutation",
          join: "contact"
       })
    ]
 });
 var searchResultCount = vendorSearchObj.runPaged().count;
 vendorSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
    // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
     log.debug("result", result);
     for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        log.debug(result.columns[i].name,result.getValue({name : result.columns[i].name}));
    } 
    return true;
 });
```

All the value is coming except the salutation column. But in result set the value is available. Below is the resultset value.

```
{
   recordType: "vendor",
   id: "375",
   values: {
      entityid: "KMBS",
      altemail: "",
      "contact.salutation": "Konica Jag"
   }
}
```

TIA...

Answer (score 8):

When you want the value from a `join` column, you need to specify the `join` property of `getValue` as well.

```js
result.getValue({
    name: "salutation",
    join: "contact"
});
```

Comment: Thanks... Just over looked... My Bad.
So does that mean that we cant use array of column to fetch the value ? Its a tadious way to do this as I need to hard code the value of this field. 
Or do you suggest some alternative..

Comment: You can alternatively pass a `search.Column` Object to `getValue`. I've not seen a need to genericize the reading of search results. I typically isolate my business logic so that there is one function to retrieve the results, one function to map the `Result` Objects to native JS Objects, then a separate module for the business logic to process the data.

Comment: What do you mean by `search.Coulumn` in getValue ? Is it `getValue{name:"contact.salutation"}` ? If so then it does not give any result though it does not through any error . <br/>
Pls also can you explain what do you mean by Object to Native JS Obj ?